# how to arrange asterisks in triangle

Tags: c, for-loop

I need to be able to print a right triangle with asterisks, making the user enter `n` rows like this and using only a `for` loop (it's an exercise for college).

```
enter number of rows: 5.
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

So far this is what i was able to do and it outputs this

```
5 rows:
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Where is the desired versus the actual output?

Comment: Hint: in each line, what is the relation between number of spaces and number of stars?

Comment: currently i can make it print in this order
*****
****
***
**
*

i dont know how to put spaces so it print
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
(they should be on top of the other from big to small, it doesnt show here in order)

basically the same traingle, inverted aligned to the right

Comment: @antimage64 would be better to edit your answer with the expected and actual output as you can format it properly which you can't do in a comment

Comment: i honestly dont know how, it either put the asterisks in the same line, or it just cuts them away

Comment: @antimage64 type in the output and mark it as if it were code - that should preserve the layout

Comment: thanks, i already edited it

Comment: Don't use the *variadic* `printf` to output a *single-character*, use the proper tool for the job (`putchar` or `fputc`), e.g. `putchar ('*');` and `putchar ('\n');`  (yes, a good compiler should do it for you, but that's not a guarantee...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = n; i > 0; i--){
        for (j = n - i; j > 0; j--){
            printf(" "); //print the blank spaces before the stars
        }
        for(j = i; j>0; j--){
            printf("*"); //print the stars
        }
        printf("\n"); //next line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

E.g: Input = 5

Output:

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Comment: thank you very much, very clear i can understand the logic of it now.

Comment: @antimage64 you're welcome. I edited the code so you can reuse the variable 'j' instead of using a new one 'k' as I wrote before.

Comment: The modern style of using `printf("X")` to output single characters still grates; that's what `putchar()` is for.  The blanks could be output by a single `printf()` statement.   With a little preparation, you could output the spaces and stars in a single `printf()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you study the (POSIX) specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) carefully and do a little preparation work, you'll find that you can print each line with a single call to `printf()`.  The code below uses no feature that is specific to POSIX, but the documentation referenced is the POSIX specification, which is a superset of the standard C specification.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of stars: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0 && n < 1000)
    {
        putchar('\n');
        char stars[n];
        char space[n];
        memset(stars, '*', n);
        memset(space, ' ', n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%.*s%.*s\n", i, space, n-i, stars);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `%.*s` notation reads an `int` from an argument to `printf()` before the string, and uses that to determine the maximum length to print.  The code uses two VLA (variable length array) variables to hold stars and spaces (I elected to preserve symmetry rather than optimize by noting that the code could use one less space than it does stars), which are set with `memset()`.  Because the code is limiting the length used, it does not matter that the arrays are not strings (no null termination).  It would be feasible to use:

```
int space[n+1];
memset(space, ' ', n);
space[n] = '\0';
```

(and similarly for `stars`) to create null-terminated strings, but it isn't crucial in this context.  However, it is crucial to know what you're doing; making them into strings is safer.

The call to `putchar('\n');` ensures that the stars start on a new line even if the program is invoked `./program <<< '10'` using a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) to supply the input rather than typing it each time.

Sample output:

```
Enter number of stars: 10

**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

This was from a run where the standard input was not coming from a here string.  This was from a run where I did use a here string:

```
Enter number of stars: 
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

Comment: I am voting this up for awesomeness, but ... kinda not the point of understanding the alg, and sort of running before you can fly...

Comment: @GradyPlayer: In many ways, it is overkill — but it shows there's more than one way to do it (the motto for Perl).  There are certainly other close relatives — IIRC, the CS50 course ([tag:cs50]) has a question about creating a ramp similar to Mario Brothers, with the top line a right-adjusted `#` and such like.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on the answers filling an variable length array with `"*"`s would be to use a single VLA as a string by adding a *nul-byte* as a final additional character to the end. That would allow simple pointer arithmetic to handle the spaces and stars for you with a simplified single *field width* specifier in `printf`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) : 5;
    char stars[n+1];  /* declare stars to hold an additional character */

    memset (stars, '*', n);
    stars[n] = 0;     /* nul-terminate at index n */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%*s\n", n, stars + i);

    return 0;
}
```

(of course you should validate `n > 0` in your code)

The above code takes the number of stars to print in a right-triangle as the first argument allowing you to specify the number of stars to print on the command line (using a default of `5` if no argument is given).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/triangle 10
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

If your compiler does not support the C99 VLA extensions, then you can either dynamically allocate, or stick with nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

One single loop, using `printf()` precision specifiers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, chk;
    chk = scanf("%d", &n);
    if ((chk != 1) || (n < 1) || (n > 32)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid n.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) printf("%*.*s%*.*s\n", n - i, n - i, " ", i, i, "************************");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Close, just change one of your conditions for it to work.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = n; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // i is the number of stars to print
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfil requirements - the triangle is meant to be aligned to the right not the left.

Comment: @ChrisTurner I am pretty sure "right triangle" means a triangle with 90 degree angle...

Comment: @EugeneSh. it does...the requirements do say about putting spaces before the lines below the top one though

Comment: @ChrisTurner Right, sorry. This is why an example of the output is desired.

Comment: yeah, right traingle is a 90 degrees triangle, but i need it to align it to the right

Comment: Also, the value of `n` (Enter the number of rows:) is ignored in this one so it always only does 5 rows.